# Highlighting selected GridView items in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to highlight the selected items in my Grid View. I added `setMultiChoiceModeListener` to my GridView and selecting items is working fine.
But while selecting the items thy are not highlighted, so the user can't se which items are selected currently.
I tried `android:state_activated="true"`, `android:state_selected="true"` and `android:state_checked="true"`, but nothing works.

Here is my current selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/grid_state_pressed" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/grid_state_active" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The pressed state is working, but I don't know why selected items are not highlighted.
Do I have to add anything else?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the exact same problem. There seems to be a bug in Android somehow, although the setActivated(true); method is called on the particular grid item view, the background selector does not update the viewDrawableState.

I fixed the issue by overriding the setActivated method on the root container of the grid item view.

```
public class GridLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public GridLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GridLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        super.setActivated(activated);

        if(activated) {
            setBackgroundResource(R.color.grid_state_pressed);
        } else {
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grid_state_selector);
        }
    }
}
```